# Is there a way to close cmus without quitting?

Tags: music, remote-control

I'm using **cmus** to listen to music now.One problem is that I couldn't close the interface while listening, i.e. keep it running background.The raw '&' doesn't work.I know **moc(p)** has the function,just pressing 'q', is there a similar way for cmus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written a guide explaining how to use a bash script combined with a rebinding of the <kbd>q</kbd> key to have very comfortable detaching/reattaching with cmus, see
https://github.com/cmus/cmus/wiki/detachable-cmus

Please tell me if this is good enough, since implementing this in cmus would be a lot of work :-).

**Note**: For the above solution to work the `screen` command must be installed: `sudo apt-get install screen`

Comment: Thanks a lot and I feel so happy that the daemon mode has been in the to-do list:)

Comment: The mentioned guide also has snippets for `tmux` :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how I work with cmus :

I run cmus manually on tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) every time I login to my computer.

I control cmus from my gnome terminal using `cmus-remote` commands (look at manpage of [cmus-remote](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/cmus-remote.1.html).

That way you can exit the terminal any time you want and still have cmus running in tty1.

Comment: ill just add that this could be possibly done with screen too, just run cmus in screen, detach and work with cmus-remote

Comment: Thanks.However I really would like cmus to have this feature anyway.